# How to retrieve unique contacts using contentresolver from Android

Tags: android, contacts

```
contactUri=ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI;//contactUri for contactscontract
contactsCursor=getContentResolver().query(contactUri,null,null,null,Phone.DISPLAY_NAME +" ASC");
```

I want distinct data (Contact name) from contacts table.

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean you got duplicate record for some contacts. So you must add condition for your query.

try this:

```
  String selection = ContactsContract.Contacts.IN_VISIBLE_GROUP + " = '"
                + ("1") + "'";
        String sortOrder = ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME
                + " COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC";
cur = context.getContentResolver().query(
                ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, projection, selection
                        + " AND " + ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER
                        + "=1", null, sortOrder);// this query only return contacts which had phone number and not duplicated
```

Comment: did you get my question.I want distinct contact name from contactscontract

Comment: what is that new String[]{id}

Comment: whats problem? please post your output.